# How can I share a local Subversion repository between a Mac workstation and a Windows virtual machine?

Tags: windows, macos, apache, svn, vmware

I would like to share a Subversion repository between my main computer running OS X Lion and a virtual machine running Windows 7 hosted in this computer (via VMware). I am unsure what is the best way to go about this.

I am thinking of setting up Apache and Subversion server on the OS X side and hopefully that would allow my virtual to access the repository from the Windows virtual using something like Tortoise SVN and accessing the repository at http://macHostName/pathToRepository. This seems feasible since the OS X side is always running.

An alternative could be setting up Apache and Subversion on the Windows virtual, which would require me to run the virtual everytime I want to access the repository from the OS X side. Perhaps Subversion can be set up in IIS? That would save some time if I don't need to install Apache.

Either way, I am unsure of the best way to go about this set up and what the caveats of each option are. I also haven't found a good walkthrough that will show how to set up a Subversion server on any OS using Apache.

Then, there is also the option of using svnserve, which I am unfamiliar with. Will a repository not served by an HTTP server like Apache be accessible for whoever is not serving it from the OS X host and the Windows virtual?

Any pointers will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both Apache and svnserve are using network protocols, so the basic network setup between your host and your guest regarding routing and firewalls will be the same.

If you already have Apache installed and are familiar to it, I recommend to use it. Otherwise my recommendation is *svnserve*, because it is much simpler to setup and configure. The SVN-Book has a [chapter](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.6/svn-book.html#svn.serverconfig.svnserve) for setting up *svnserve* both in Windows and in OSX.